# how to modify space between cells in apexchart heatmap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I want to expand the space between cells in Apexcharts' Heatmap.

I have a heatmap that functions smoothly, however, I want to highlight several tiles by changing the color of their strokes. Then, I realized that since all tiles are aligned closely with no actual space between, part of the stroke would be covered by other neighbor cells, which makes the highlight only half effective.

[image: img]

This is what happen when I change the stroke color, the right half of the stroke is covered by the neighbor cell (both left one and the bottom one)

[image]

Any help would be appreaciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you change the radius value? See here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/heatmap/

Comment: @rguttersohn Thank you for your suggestion, I tried, but it didnt help... when i decrease the radius, the space between cells hardly changes. when i increase the radius, even to a really high value like 100, there are still overlapping space between cells, plus with such great radius, the grid is no longer a rectangle, which is not desired.....

Comment: Ah ok. I looked through the options for heat map and that was the only thing that seemed like it would tackle it. You might have to manually change the box width using vanilla JS after the visual is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space between the cells in your `ApexCharts` heatmap by applying this CSS code, that's what I used:

```
.apexcharts-series.apexcharts-heatmap-series rect {
    stroke: none;
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```